# tensorflow.ones_like on a SparseTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

In tensorflow, I want to do tf.ones_like on a SparseTensor; however, it seems it only works for normal (dense) tensors. Do you know any function or workaround?

As an example, I want to go from [['aa','ab','ac'],['ba','bb', UND],['ca',UND,UND] to [[1,1,1],[1,1,UND],[1,UND,UND]], where UND = undefined.

Thanks!

Comment: A sparse tensor is the most inefficient representation for a tensor of 1s. That's why there is no `ones_like` for sparse tensors. Can't you use a normal dense tensor?

Comment: @E_net4 Can I represent a tensor like [[1,1,1],[1,1]] (in some dimensions different rows have different lengths) in dense format? If so, how?

Comment: Sparse tensors don't really have rows of variable lengths, although they can expand on any dimension cheap. I think you should include a small description of what you are trying to do, along with some code.

Comment: @E_net4 you're right; I improved my example in the question, hopefully this helps illustrate what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. Convert sparse to dense and then create a ones tensor. Something like `tf.ones_like(tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(x))`
2. Get a shape of sparse tensor and use it to create a ones tensor. It looks like [dense_shape does this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor#dense_shape). Then use [tf.ones](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ones) with that shape.